# Getting data automatically from CiviCRM to Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: export, google

Is there an easy (semi-)automatic way to get data from CiviCRM to Google Spreadsheets?

Data on CiviCRM side could come from search results (smart group) or a report.

On Google Spreadsheets side I would like to import data in specific document and replace particular sheet. Other sheets would then contain formulas to retrieve and process data from the imported sheet.

I would like the whole process to run it with a single click or even time-based (cron) to save time and eliminate human error in the process of exporting and re-importing regularly.

Has anyone seen or made anything similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out this recording of a CiviCon session? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6K3awPdA7h0. Not sure if it will answer all your questions but I am sure it will give you a good idea :-)

Comment: Link to blog post: https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/06/custom-regular-reporting-from-civicrm-with-google-sheets-and-google-apps-script/